# Couldn't detect http error for API less than 21

Tags: android, webview

I have an Android Webview code which fails to detect HTTP errors for API less than 21.

> What I have tried:

have done several trial and errors with

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, noconnection.class);
            intent.putExtra("a", "mainactivity is source");
            startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured, please check Network Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
```

> Another method:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        if(error.getErrorCode() == -8 || error.getErrorCode() == -14 || error.getErrorCode() == -6){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, noconnection.class);
            intent.putExtra("a", "mainactivity is source");
            startActivity(intent);

            mWebview.clearCache(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured, please check Network Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }
```

both of them are not working. *onReceivedHttpError* works fine though which works only for API above 21.

have refered various post on stack, but result is always same.

It will be very helpful if anyone could point out the underlying issue.

> Code:

```
package com.test.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;


import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static WebView mWebview;
    private android.content.Context Context;
    private static String getIntentValue = null;
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Context = this;

        getIntentValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("value");

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String token1 = sharedPreferences.getString("regtoken", null);
        Log.d(TAG, "TOKEN===>" + token1);

        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish(); //Calling this method to close this activity when internet is not available.
        } else {
            mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
            mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new JsPopupWebViewChrome());
            mWebview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

            //improve WebView Performance
            mWebview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
            mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
            webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
            webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

            // progress dialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Context);

            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isKeyGenerated", true)) {

                if (getIntentValue != null) {
                    mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
                    getIntentValue = null;

                } else {
                    mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class JsPopupWebViewChrome extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                    .setTitle("ALERT!")
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            result.confirm();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            result.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            b.show();

            // Indicate that we're handling this manually
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Function to load all URLs in same webview
    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(Context)) {
                Toast.makeText(Context, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (url.startsWith("http://www.example.com")) {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "Say Bye Bye to Hospital Waiting!!!.\n\n\nDownload This App to BOOK & Keep Track of your Number in Hospital.\n\nhttp://www.example.com";
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            }  else if (url.contains("youtube")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            //on page started, show loading page
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            String currentPage= mWebview.getUrl();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("currentpage",currentPage);
            editor.commit();

            //after loading page, remove loading page

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, noconnection.class);
                intent.putExtra("a", "mainactivity is source");
                startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured, please check Network Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                if(errorResponse.getStatusCode() == 408 || errorResponse.getStatusCode() == 404){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, noconnection.class);
                    intent.putExtra("a", "mainactivity is source");
                    startActivity(intent);

                    mWebview.clearCache(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured, please check Network Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            if(error.getErrorCode() == -8 || error.getErrorCode() == -14 || error.getErrorCode() == -6){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, noconnection.class);
                intent.putExtra("a", "mainactivity is source");
                startActivity(intent);

                mWebview.clearCache(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured, please check Network Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }

    }

    //-------------


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String currenturl = sharedPreferences.getString("currentpage", null);

        mWebview.requestFocus();

        if (currenturl.contains("http://www.example.com")){
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }else{
            mWebview.goBack();
        }

    }


    public static void loadUrl(String key) {

        if (getIntentValue != null) {
            mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
            getIntentValue = null;
        } else {
            mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
        }

    }


    public static void reLoad() {
        mWebview.reload();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think maybe you have to call super. ... first and than excute your code.

Comment: still nothing. same result